# What ants are in our house?

Tags: ants

Trying to figure out what ants are in our house? [image]

Comment: not termites maybe carpenter ants

Comment: Getting a scale of the size of the ant would help identify it.  Currently, it's impossible to tell if it's an inch long, or a 1/16" of an inch, at least from the picture you provided with no other objects to get a sense of size.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Greg it seems you gave created 2 accounts. Please ask a moderator to combine them. And please dont ask the same question again.

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Nnr6iOL7LTI/maxresdefault.jpg